# Export flextable as html

Tags: flextable

If I print a flextable object, it get displayed as html in a browser.
Is there a way of saving the html.  I am using 0.5.1 version of flextable.

Answer (score 0):

You can produce an HTML document containing a flextable with R Markdown. The following is extracted from the documentation - this is how flextable can be used in R Markdown documents:

````
> this is how to print a flextable in a R Markdown document

```{r eval=FALSE}
library(magrittr)
mytable <- cars %>% 
  head() %>% 
  flextable() %>% 
  autofit()

mytable
```
````

Comment: Is it possible to do that in standard r/officer/flextable?

Comment: if the need is to only save the result in an HTML file, use `save_as_html` (it's a new function only available in the github version for now)

Answer (score 0):

Update November 2019: the function is now available in the package version 0.5.6

```
ft <- flextable(mydataframe) # create a flextable object
save_as_html(ft, "path/to/file.html") # and save as html
```

From the documentation:
https://rdrr.io/cran/flextable/man/save_as_html.html

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers require users to export (i.e. save) the flextable.

To 'just' transform a `flextable` object to HTML, use their `htmltools_value()` function:

```r
library(dplyr) # for the pipe
library(flextable)
mtcars %>%
  flextable() %>%
  htmltools_value()
```

This is ideal for adding a flextable to e.g. an email object (using the `blastula` package or the `Microsoft365R` package for example).